# How to install OpenJDK Java 11 on a RHEL 7.2 server

Tags: java, linux, rhel7, openjdk-11

I am not able to install openjdk11 on RHEL 7.2.

I have tried as

```
**yum install java-11-openjdk-devel**
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
                                                                                                                                   | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-eus-optional-rpms                                                                                                                                                         | 1.8 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-eus-rpms                                                                                                                                                                  | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-eus-supplementary-rpms                                                                                                                                                    | 1.8 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                                                                                                                                                               | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms                                                                                                                                                             | 1.8 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms                                                                                                                                                            | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                                                                      | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.9-rpms                                                                                                                                                  | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms                                                                                                                                                        | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
**No package java-11-openjdk-devel available**.
**Error: Nothing to do**
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if you do not have the license to the RHEL repo, you could use the equivalent CentOS repos.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the RPM via the RHEL 7.x package repository, but maybe you don't have access to that repository.  (Access it restricted to people / organizations with a RHEL license, I think.)  If you do, the `yum install` approach should work.

You can also find RPMs for OpenJDK Java using https://rpmfind.net.  For example:

- https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-11-openjdk-devel gives download links for the available versions of OpenJDK Java 11 from from https://openjdk.java.net/

The rpmfind site doesn't list any RHEL endorsed packages, but the CentOS 7.x packages should be compatible with RHEL 7.2.  Or you *could* upgrade<sup>1</sup> RHEL.

After downloading (e.g. using `wget`) you can manually install an RPM using

```
sudo rpm -i example_file.rpm
```

or

```
sudo yum localinstall example_file.rpm
```

The downside of a local install is that `yum` won't be able to upgrade it for you.  You will need to repeat the above steps each time there is a new patch release for Java 11.

---

<sup>1 - I suspect that if you upgraded your OS to the latest RHEL 7.x release or an 8.x release, you would be able to install OpenJDK Java 11 from the RHEL package repos.</sup>